# SQL Assistant with Where Clause

Tags: sqlite, where-clause

I am using SQLite. Below is my code and Excel screenshot of some of the columns I am using from SQLite. I am trying to create a where clause that will select the times in the registered at column that occurred before the indicated time in the vax start time column. When the data downloads it has both the date and time in the register at column. I am trying to choose the time portion to compare to the time in the vax start time column. I am trying to select the time portion as shown in the excel sheet screen shot so that I can make a where clause that will show in the results the people who registered before the vax start time and have them indicated as pre registered. I tried to use like and the wildcard _ and %, however I get an error or the wrong results. Any suggestions on how I can choose the times in the register at column that occurred before the vax start time?

[Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CK1iU.jpg)

```
SELECT * 
FROM COREGAMasterDatabasePowerBI AS A 

JOIN COREGAScheduling15 AS B 

ON soundex(A.Location) LIKE soundex(B.Site_Name) AND A.Visit_time=B.Date 

ORDER BY B.date ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

To simplify matters you should use a recognised date/time format when storing data in SQLite. e.g. YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss

- It is suspected that an assumption has been made that SQLite is as comprehensive as MS Excel at handling dates. SQLite is not. Unless using the date/time functions (link below) a date is simple a binary stream of bytes when being sorted or compared.
- although possible other solutions will require manipulating the data, complicated as the date and month can be either 1 or 2 characters. The manipulation being required at least one per column.

see https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

- otherwise you will likely have issues e.g. `ORDER BY B.date ASC` will sort according to month then day then year if using a format like 9/12/2023 and furthermore 11/12/2023 will be considered before 9/12/2023 (i.e. the 1 for the 10 is less than 9).

Using recognised, importantly sortable/comparable date formats, then it is relatively simple as you could use something like:-

```
SELECT * 
FROM COREGAMasterDatabasePowerBI AS A 
JOIN COREGAScheduling15 AS B 
ON soundex(A.Location) = soundex(B.Site_Name) AND a.visit_time < b.date
ORDER BY B.date ASC
```

**Demo** (using an SQLite tool (Navicat)):-

```
/* Just-in-case Cleanup */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS COREGAMasterDatabasePowerBI;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS COREGAScheduling15;
/* Create the tables */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS COREGAMasterDatabasePowerBI (location TEXT, visit_time TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS COREGAScheduling15 (site_name TEXT, date TEXT);
/* Load both tables with some data */
INSERT INTO COREGAScheduling15 VALUES 
    ('A','2023-09-12 12:45:00')
    ,('B','2023-09-12 11:45:00')
    ,('C','2023-09-12 10:45:00')
;
INSERT INTO COREGAMasterDatabasePowerBI VALUES
    ('A','2023-09-12 12:43:00')
    ,('A','2023-09-12 12:42:00')
    ,('A','2023-09-12 12:48:00') /* after */
    ,('B','2023-09-12 11:48:00') /* exact same time as registration */
    ,('B','2023-09-11 11:48:00')
    ,('B','2023-09-12 11:47:00')
    ,('B','2023-08-12 11:48:00')
;
/* Demo output 1 - Original just changed slightly */
SELECT * 
FROM COREGAMasterDatabasePowerBI AS A 
JOIN COREGAScheduling15 AS B 
ON soundex(A.Location) = soundex(B.Site_Name) AND a.visit_time < b.date
-- WHERE a.visit_time < b.date
ORDER BY B.date ASC
;
/* Demo output 2 - Original but WHERE clause as opposed to JOIN expression */
SELECT * 
FROM COREGAMasterDatabasePowerBI AS A 
JOIN COREGAScheduling15 AS B 
ON soundex(A.Location) = soundex(B.Site_Name)
WHERE a.visit_time < b.date
ORDER BY B.date ASC
;
/* Demo Output 3 - Show both sorts (PREG or AT OR POSTREG) */
SELECT 'PREREG',* 
FROM COREGAMasterDatabasePowerBI AS A 
JOIN COREGAScheduling15 AS B 
ON soundex(A.Location) = soundex(B.Site_Name) AND a.visit_time < b.date
-- WHERE a.visit_time < b.date
UNION ALL SELECT 'AT OR POSTREG',*
FROM COREGAMasterDatabasePowerBI AS A 
JOIN COREGAScheduling15 AS B 
ON soundex(A.Location) = soundex(B.Site_Name) AND a.visit_time >= b.date
ORDER BY B.date ASC
;
/* Cleanup demo environment */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS COREGAMasterDatabasePowerBI;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS COREGAScheduling15;
```

The resultant outputs (SELECTS):-

**Demo 1**

[image]

**Demo 2**  (i.e. identical data to demo 1)

[image]

**Demo 3**

[image]